# Mutator como Atributo padrão

Tags: laravel

Tenho um mutator similar a este:

```
public function getLastTotalAttribute()
{
  return $this->produto->sold_on_register;
}
```

Quero que o atributo last_total seja automaticamente gerado na consulta, assim como os atributos comuns do `$fillable`.

Preciso utilizar a collection via API e não tenho mais acesso as propriedades do objeto quando faço isso.

---

EDIT 1:

Para simplificar a compreensão:

Usuarios possui produto, e o produto possui o sold_on_register.

Eu quero ter acesso ao atributo do produto através do usuário, porém, não farei isso no blade para poder utilizar o método mutator, preciso que este atributo seja inserido por padrão.

Exemplo:

`User::find(1)` terá os atributos comuns do user

`User::find(1)->last_total` acessará o atributo do mutador se eu fizer isso no blade ou no controller.

Preciso que o last_total seja incluso nos atributos naturalmente no `User::find(1)` para a API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar um campo a técnica utilizada é [serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization). Precisa criar realmente um [acessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) como você mesmo criou, mas, precisa dizer para seu modelo mais uma configuração:

```
protected $appends = ['last_total'];
```

***Um exemplo completo:***

**Classe** `User`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    protected $appends = ['last_total']; // adicionando item na serialização

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getLastTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->product->name;
    }
}
```

**Classe** `Product`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name' ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
return \App\User::find(1);
```

**Saída:**

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"user 1",
    "email":"user1@user.com",
    "created_at":"2018-03-22 04:03:33",
    "updated_at":"2018-03-22 04:03:33",
    "last_total":"Product 1",
    "product":{ 
                  "id":1,
                  "user_id":1,
                  "name":"Product 1",
                  "updated_at":"2018-03-22 04:05:04",
                  "created_at":"2018-03-22 04:05:04"
              }
 }
```

***Note*** que esse exemplo é para relação 1:1 como eu pude entender pelo seu código, mas, a estratégia é sempre essa, crie um [acessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) depois configure o `appends`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [eloquent-serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization)
- [eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)